# How to make ui for supporting all the screens?

Tags: user-interface, cordova

I am new to phonegap.

I am implementing html with cordova.

But the problem is the screens are not adjestred properly for android and iPhone.

If any one know ,Please  help me

Comment: Share your code that will help to answer your question

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use a framework like [jQueryMobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) or [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) to handle all screen sizes

Answer (score 0):

One solution is using viewport meta tag. For more detail, your refer to the below links:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag#Common_Viewport_Sizes_for_Mobile_and_Tablet_devices

http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/cssmediaqueries3.shtml

Other solution, you can use Javascript library such as monaca.viewport.js (https://github.com/monaca/monaca.js, http://docs.monaca.mobi/en/reference/javascript/monaca_viewport/).